# Is there an adjective, stronger than "simplistic", that would fit here?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> The IHO stated: “Courts in the Second Circuit have uniformly held that an ‘adverse effect on a student’s educational performance’ encompasses only academic performance and does not encompass social/behavioral functioning.”  But it would be _____________ to assume that every historically important legal precedent applies equally to every student.

*Simplistic* isn't judgmental enough.  I need something stronger.

Comment: How about naïve, risible, fallacious, imprudent, reckless, unconscionable, preposterous, unethical, irresponsible, ingenuous, unrealistic, delusional, impolitic, or imbecilic. Don

Comment: It would *run counter to the individuality of human nature*?  Too much of a mouthful!  I think there's a word out there that you smart guys here on ELU will know, that I don't have a good enough vocabulary to come up with. // It would *reduce humanity's children to tin soldiers*?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus? If so, why did you reject its suggestions? I'm surprised that with your rep you're posting a question without any research!

Comment: @AndyT - I love using a thesaurus.  But before you use a thesaurus, you need to know the meaning of the word you're looking for.  This is a harder question than the usual.  In this case, I can't tell you what the word should mean.  I just have the sentence it should go in.  // If it helps, of the words proposed so far, *imprudent* is the only one that feels remotely possible.  In these legal things, you have to show a certain detachment.

Comment: @aparente001 - I'm clearly missing something here. You want a word but you don't know what that word should mean? Surely you want a word that means "simplistic in a bad way" (as you suggest "simplistic" as being not judgmental enough)? A thesaurus for [simplistic](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/simplistic%20?s=t) gives childish (which I think is slightly more judgmental), and clicking on [childish](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/childish) gives "naïve".

Comment: @AndyT - That is correct.  I want a word but I don't know what that word should mean.

Comment: [cont.]  Clicking on the definition for [naïve](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/naive) says that it means "having or showing unaffected simplicity of nature" (so it's relating to simplistic, good). To me, "naïve" is quite judgmental, unless used for a small child who you would not expect to have any cynicism yet. So it sounds like the perfect word, and as well as my thoughts that it's good, two others have posted it in answers. And yet we have no clue why you've rejected it (there are no upvotes on the answers, so you clearly don't like it).

Comment: @aparente001 - So you don't want a word that means "simplistic in a bad way"? If you don't want that, then you haven't communicated what you want in any way, shape, or form, which would make this unanswerable!

Comment: Perfect word: shortsighted (at least that's the word I think you're looking for). Shortsighted: not given careful consideration (thefreedictionary.com); myopic in thinking. Don

Comment: I think you have a problem with the sentence.  "But it would be _____________ to assume that every historically important legal precedent applies equally to every student".  What you are trying to say is how the legal precedent was applied in one case does not dictate how it be applied in another case.  I know this is awkward, and I am not a lawyer, but IMO, you need to rewrite the sentence, not try to put all the work on the shoulders of one word.

Comment: @ab2 - I guess I ended up doing what you are suggesting (see new answer).  I don't know if I did it as well as you were hoping, but I felt more satisfied with what I ended up with than in the first draft that had "simplistic."

Answer (score 2):

To my ear, **facile** is a harsher characterization than **simplistic**, but that's just my opinion. Here's the relevant definition of *facile* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **facile** *adj* ... 2 : SHALLOW, SIMPLISTIC {I am not concerned ... with offering  any *facile* solution for so complex a problem —T. S. Eliot}

Answer (score 1):

Ignorant or naive? These words imply a lack of understanding of the whole picture, or implying that they are not taking in (or are not aware) of external factors that will undoubtedly make that statement a gross simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes some adjectives get stronger with the help of an adverb.I recommend you write *absurdly simplistic* for example. Οr a very judgemental adjective that suits here is *naive*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I put after the quote:

> This is an **unwarranted blanket statement**.  Not every historically important decision applies equally to every student.

Comment: What is IHO?  I had to Google it, and after I convinced Google that I did not mean IHOP the first thing that came up was International Hydrographic Organization.  That didn't sound right.  Eventually, I found http://www.abbreviations.com/IHO and deduced that IHO In your context was Impartial Hearing Officer.  TMW! (too much work :))

Comment: @ab2 - I'm very sorry, I didn't notice I had used an acronym.  Bingo, you found it.  Yes, it is Impartial Hearing Officer.